# How can i remove footer credit text

Tags: themes, css

My website has footer credit which is really hard for me to hide or remove or replace please help me , I'm using painting theme from **themeforest**.

I even tried this also:

```
.site-info{
  display:none;
}
```

Comment: Check your theme options settings for footer, I am sure there is a option for hide or remove copyright. You don't need to hide it using css if there is any default options for hide it.

Answer (score 0):

It's going to be hard to answer this without being able to see the theme admin. Check to see if there are any theme customisation options in your admin. Some themes may come with their own control panel which lets you toggle settings or alter footer content, like the copyright.

The theme may also have a hook to let you filter and alter the content, again without access to the code I am only guessing here.

A good solution here would be to [create a child theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/) from this, and create a new footer.php template to override the content. Make a copy of the current footer.php and place it in your child theme, and then simply remove the copyright.

Lastly, check the terms and conditions on this theme you have purchased as you may not be allowed to remove the copyright notice.

Comment: Please Read carefully the Question. He is not exactly say remove. he is say "Footer credit which is really hard for me to hide or remove or replace ". so why overwrite template if the theme setting replace or hide the text?

Comment: Because we have no idea if there is a theme setting to remove/replace the text. Hence why I've given several solutions.

Answer (score -1):

Please use the below code to remove the footer copyright information.

```
.copyright p {
display: none;
}
```

This will work fine.

Comment: Damn! love you man it's done thanks a lot. could you please tell me also how can i put mine i'm using painting theme from themeforest

Comment: This is hiding the content, not removing it.

Answer (score -1):

Css is not a proper. you are using premium theme then use theme setting. check the theme setting or footer widgth for remove or change this text.